# How can I send a literal tab to bash in emacs' shell-mode?

Tags: emacs

I want to bypass comint-mode's completion support completely, instead relying on the subordinate process to do it for me. Specifically, if I'm running:

- emacs

  - shell-mode

    - bash

Then I want `TAB` to be passed to the bash process and expanded by it.

If I'm running:

- emacs

  - shell-mode

    - bash

      - psql

Then I'd want `TAB` to be handled by psql.

I've tried this in a shell-mode-hook to no avail:

```
(define-key shell-mode-map "\t" 'self-insert-command)
```

When this is set, the `TAB` key inserts a literal tab on the command line, which is not at all useful to me.

I've also tried this, but when I hit `TAB` nothing happens:

```
(defun cr/comint-send-tab ()
  "Send a tab character to the current buffer's process"
  (interactive)
  (comint-send-input t t)
  (process-send-string (current-buffer) "\t"))

(define-key shell-mode-map "\t" 'cr/comint-send-tab)
```

How can I do this?

Comment: +1: I had been exploring almost exactly the same use case when I found this question!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Emacs `shell-mode` buffers are not terminals (i.e., they do not use ptys (pseudo-terminals)), so no program running in such a buffer (the shell, the programs run by the shell, etc.) can perform character-at-a-time input.  Each line is typed in full and only sent when <kbd>ENTER</kbd> is pressed.  To see proof, run the `tty` command in a `shell-mode` buffer, and it's output will be `not a tty`.

Comment: FYI, while it may seem that this is not true because you can perform command-line editing with `Ctrl-B`, `Ctrl-F`, etc., this is only because shell-mode itself simulates the typical command-line editing features of shell's like Bash, Zsh, Korn shell, etc. using Emacs own internal editing capabilities.

Answer (score 3):

Try `quoted-insert` which is (by default) bound to <kbd>C-q</kbd>. The next character you type will be literally inserted into the buffer.

So <kbd>C-q</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd> will insert a literal tab.

I don't know what this does in *comint* modes (in regard to bash completion) and am not in a position to test it.

Comment: That has the same effect as my second attempt, above. No go, sadly.

Answer (score 2):

How about trying Emacs' [terminal](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Terminal-emulator.html) (instead of shell).

<kbd>M-x term</kbd>

Comment: Term has its own set of issues, starting with some interesting interactions with my extant set of bashrc tweaks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use bash's quote character, which is Ctrl-V.  To insert a literal TAB into bash running in Emacs' shell buffer, do

> `C-q C-v C-q TAB`